# Magento: translating payment-method-charge

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have Magento version 1.7.0.2, I've installed a component from the Magento Connect: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payment-method-charge.html) this sets a cost for "Cash on receipt" Method.

I have the front page showing this:

[image]

Which is connected to the following backend Payment Module (Config > Payment Methods):

[image]

I don't need to translate the Backend, but at least the front end, it should display "Contrassegno" instead of "Payment Charge".

I cannot find where to do this, is it possible the lang file is missing for this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Magento's inline translation feature or CSV translate file.

For inline translation, visit following

http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/

Comment: Tks! Any more detail to this? Like where do I have to place it and what kind of variable I have to pass in the csv?

Comment: Are you using custom theme or default theme ?

Comment: I'm writing from iPhone, once in office I'll check and let u know. Tks a lot for now

Comment: @empiro looks like is a custom theme.

Comment: Yes! That's why I checked your answer. Tks